# React Fetching Multiple APIs That Depend On Each Other (async/await)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a project, and I ran into this error

> "response.json is not a function"

I can get the lat and long after fetching the data from the first API call just fine. But after I nested the 2nd API into the first one the problem occurs.

I'm not sure what I'm doing in wrong here. What are the ways to solve this whether or not the APIs depend on each other? Thanks in advance

```
const Form = () => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    geocode()

  }, [location])

  const geocode = async () => {
    if(location) {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${location}.json?limit=1&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      const lat = data.features[0].center[1]
      const log = data.features[0].center[0]
      console.log(data.features[0].center[1], data.features[0].center[0])
      forecast(lat,log)
    }
  }

  const forecast = async (latitude, longitude) => {
    const response = await `https://api.darksky.net/forecast//${API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}`
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
  }

  const getSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLocation(search)
    setSearch('')
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={getSubmit}>
      <input 
        type="text"
        name="location"
        value={search}
        onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter Location..."/>
      <button type="submit">Get weather!</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: same as geocode, use `fetch()`, voting to close as typo error.

Comment: Nice catch, I'll see it anything still occurs

Comment: @codekaizer now I got this error "Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/4b24129feacca9b38aac8f2021b82534/37.8267,-122.4233' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: that's a different question. you may want to close this one as typo and open another.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually sending your request,

```
await `https://api.darksky.net/forecast//${API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}`
```

it should be

```
await fetch(`https://api.darksky.net/forecast//${API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}`)
```

Comment: Silly me, I made a typo while posting this code to stackoverflow. It still doesn't work after I fixed it.